# Como crear un instalador ejecutable para Mac?

Tags: macos

Previamente he creado (con [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), pascal) un instalador para windows ([Aqui el Link](https://storage.googleapis.com/credible-cab-5917/installers/setupSICARv2.2.exe)) el cual cuenta con paginas personalizadas, campos de texto, combo box, radio buttons, scripts, licencia, modos de instalación, entre otros, este es mi instalador para Windows:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- He estado investigando como replicarlo en Mac, puesto que quiero hacer un instalador nativo.
- Me he encontrado con [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html), que puedes crear Plug-Ins pero no encontré la función de saltar paginas al igual que el instalador que creé.
- Encontré PackageMaker (Apple) y fue lo mismo, no puedo crear un instalador así de personalizado.

Encontré que Opera cuenta con un instalador personalizado, es mas o menos así lo que quiero lograr (Siguiente, siguiente, atras, etc.) pero no encuentro una manera de hacerlo en MacOS :[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es crear un instalador dmg?

Comment: Lo que quiero es crear un instalador para capturar datos del usuario, ahora mismo edito mi pregunta para incluir mas información.

Comment: Creo que seria un instalador .app, ya que no he encontrado la manera de modificar el pkg a mis necesidades, una vez creado lo metere en un dmg, pero para eso no hay mayor inconveniente ya que es muy facil, muchas gracias por comentar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo creando una Cocoa Application con `XCODE`, solo tendrías que crear las vistas del ViewController, con botones puedes cambiar entre las vistas y añadir funcionalidad a la hora de cambiar entre ellas, así solucionas lo de la compatibilidad puesto que el resultado final sera una `.app` que podrás ejecutar en MacOS sin necesidad de instalar nada, el problema es que quizá sea un poco complicado crear un instalador desde cero.

Otra opción es utilizar el [IZPACK](http://izpack.org) pero desconozco hasta que punto se puede personalizar, ademas de que no seria nativo.